# Cant access and execute a script on remote node using Ansible Tower

Tags: shell, automation, ansible, ansible-tower, remote-host

I have a similar problem but my error message says:

```
{
"changed": false,
"msg": "Could not find or access 'woshutdown.sh'
Searched in: /var/ansible/tmp/awx_29146_42q4g5dt/project/qadeployment/files/woshutdown.sh
/var/ansible/tmp/awx_29146_42q4g5dt/project/qadeployment/woshutdown.sh
/var/ansible/tmp/awx_29146_42q4g5dt/project/qadeployment/files/woshutdown.sh
/var/ansible/tmp/awx_29146_42q4g5dt/project/qadeployment/woshutdown.sh on the Ansible Controller.
If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"
}
```

My script is call woshutdown.sh and it is meant call on another script that shuts down the remote server that it is located on. I have the shabang in the beginnig of the script but im getting that message.

This is my playbook:
[Playbook for the above task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40YaI.png)

This is where the script is located:
[Location of Script on remote server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITToE.png)

I have tried Script Module I have tried CMD module and sh command. Please help!!

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as images; it hinders legibility and makes them opaque to search engines -- it's explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 1):

The current directory is never placed in the `$PATH` of a shell because it's a grave security risk. You'll want to specify the fully-qualified path to the script, which in your case, due to the `chdir:` is just `./`:

```yaml
- name: shutdown etc etc
  command: ./woshutdown.sh
  args:
    chdir: /methode/common/etc-etc-etc
```

Comment: Excellent It worked, I have received a changed value but the server still shows as on. When I executed the script manually It turns off the server but now when executed from tower it doesnt turn anything off on the remote host

Comment: You can try running the script in trace mode by `commend: bash -x ./woshutdown.sh` and see what assumption it is making, but beyond that no one on the Internet can magically guess what's wrong with your script